# Pattern to Add Behaviour using New Methods at Runtime

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, decorator, strategy-pattern

I would like to be able to use a pattern to add behaviour (by virtue of additional methods/properties) to an existing class at runtime.

This seems very similar to the well-known decorator pattern, however, the examples that I have been able to find of the decorator pattern do not allow for the *nested* addition of new methods. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
namespace Decorator {
    // classes and types
    // - component: 
    // - concrete component: 
    // - decorator: 
    // - concrete decorator: 

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            IServer serverA = new Server(); // has database services 
            IServer serverB = new Server(); // has web services
            IServer serverC = new Server(); // has both database services and web services

            // add behaviour using the decorator pattern
            serverA = new DatabaseServerDecorator(serverA);          
            serverB = new WebServerDecorator(serverB);
            serverC = new DatabaseServerDecorator(serverA);
            serverC = new WebServerDecorator(serverA); // note the 2nd level which causes loss of 'awareness' of the DbDecorator

            // test restart of servers 
            serverA.RestartServer();
            serverB.RestartServer();
            serverC.RestartServer();

            // test restart of web services 
            var webServerB = serverB as WebServerDecorator;
            var webServerC = serverB as WebServerDecorator;
            webServerB.RestartWebServices();
            webServerC.RestartWebServices();

            // test restart of database services 
            var databaseServerA = serverA as DatabaseServerDecorator;
            var databaseServerC = serverC as DatabaseServerDecorator; // this will not work (HOW TO FIX??)

            databaseServerA.RestartDatabaseServices();
            databaseServerC.RestartDatabaseServices();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    // IComponent
    public interface IServer { 
        void RestartServer();
    }
    // Component
    public class Server : IServer {
        public void RestartServer() {
            Console.WriteLine("Server restarted.");
        }
    }
    // DecoratorA
    public class WebServerDecorator : IServer {
        IServer _server;
        public WebServerDecorator(IServer server) {
            _server = server;
        }
        public void RestartServer() {
            _server.RestartServer();
        }

        public void RestartWebServices() { 
            Console.WriteLine("Web services restarted."); 
        }
    }
    public class DatabaseServerDecorator : IServer {
        IServer _server;
        public DatabaseServerDecorator(IServer server) {
            _server = server;
        }
        public void RestartServer() {
            _server.RestartServer();
        }
        public void RestartDatabaseServices() {
            Console.WriteLine("Database services restarted.");
        }
    }  
}
```

(The real code would use "if object is Type" for identification, but this has been removed for conciseness/clarity)

Is this possible? In the example above, it may be possible for a server to have more than one 'service', so it would not be desirable to have to create every possible permutation (which would become unmanageable as the number of services grow).

Answer (score 0):

Calls to `Console.WriteLine("database service ..")` should belong to `RestartServer()` as it's logically belongs to "interface contract". That's the goal of Decorator pattern - you decorate behavior of what is provided by interface (but no more). Creating new methods (extending interface contract) is not what Decorator is meant to do. Not sure what you're trying to achieve but maybe you shouldn't over-abstracting it? How about having different interfaces like `IWebServer`, `IDatabaseServer` (implementing `IServer`) and decorate `IWebServer`, `IDatabaseServer` instead of `IServer`?

Comment: In this scenario, the RestartDatabaseServices() code should not belong to RestartServer() as this is a different function. Imagine, instead of RestartDatabaseServices() that we wished to add a function called GetDatabaseEngine() - this is a new method and not an extension of the RestartServer() behaviour.

Comment: If you have access, the ability to extend the contract with the decorator pattern is demonstrated in C# 3.0 Design Patterns by Judith Bishop. In this example they add a new method using the decorator pattern, however, as shown above, this approach doesn't work when adding more than one (nested) behaviour for the reasons that you mention. My question then, is what is the best approach to allow the addition of more than one new behaviour at runtime?